# Time difference in executing same API in different machines

Tags: c#, c++

My application in C#, WPF is using an API from C++ library for image processing. I need to process six images at a time, for this six objects are made available for this.
When the images are ready for processing, it will be assigned to thread from thread pool. Below code is used for this.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadPoolCallback, imageTuple);
```

In "ThreadPoolCallback" image-processing API is being called.

Coming to my issue, in my development laptop, the time for just executing the API is 3 - 3.5 Sec. But when the same code is executed in an automation system which is having an IPC which has a much better spec, the API execution time is shooting 8 - 9 Sec.

My development machine is having 8 core processor with 16 GB memory
IPC in automation system is having 14 core processor with 32 GB memory.

I have already checked basic things like memory shoot up, cpu utilization going high ext. But none of them is showing anything to be worried. Only difference in two systems is IPC is having a NI Labview set up installed.

Looking for some suggestion to improve my parallel execution time. Whether I can use dedicated cores or any other.

Thanks in advance

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadPoolCallback, imageTuple);

public void ThreadPoolCallback(Object threadContext)
        {
            try
            {

                var result = visionProcessingUnit.ExecuteInspection(imageTuple.Item3, imageTuple.Item2.ImageData, VIBitmap.Width, VIBitmap.Height);;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Exception("VisionHandler.cs", ex);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should ensure, that your live system handle 6 threads really faster. You can download and unzip 7zip on both systems and run a little benchmark from commandline with 6 threads:

```
7z b -mmt6
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will definitely take a look.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPool threads are not for long running tasks and may be occupied with some net framework processes.Usually there are 250 threads per CPU available in thread pool. Additionally you can check if you are locking some code in your method which blocks a thread pool scheduling.

I would advise you not to use thread pool thread if the task is time consuming.

Below are the two options that you can use which will use new thread instead of thread pool one.

```
var imageTuple = "blqhblah";
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ThreadPoolCallback(imageTuple),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

and

```
 var thread=new Thread(()=>ThreadPoolCallback(imageTuple));
 thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
 thread.Start();
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comments. Suggestion to use "Task" is convincing. Additionally I.would like to make one thing clear. From my analysis what I under stood is, there is no issues in getting thread, but time taking to run the API which is processing the image. Will switching to "Task" give some improvement over using thread pool.

Comment: if you borrow from Threadpool ,priority is a concern,That might be slowing down. From above solutions I try to negate that slowdown was not because of priority.You might get a thread but it will wait for his turn on taskscheduler.